# How to route between two or more private network?

Tags: google-compute-engine

if I create default2 network in GCE with 192.168.3.0/24 network, how do I route with default network? do I have to create routable instance which will act as a router?

Answer (score 1):

The networks are completely isolated so you can two instances that belong to different networks with the same internal IP and that's why it's not possible to communicate between instances that belong to different networks using the internal IP

Also, as [stated in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#networks_1):

> Any communication between instances in different networks, even within the same project, must be through external IP addresses.

As you said, the best way to allow traffic between these networks is [setting up a VPN gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#settingupvpn) but this will require to have different IP address ranges in those networks because routing of network packets may get confused.